# How to update the json data (i.e using Id value) in python django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want Update the data to use put request
update the data by using Employee Id Value
first retrieve the data which we pass id number and update that particular Id data

```
        def put(self, request, pk):
        employeeid = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = employeeSerializer(employeeid, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have this sample code but I didn't get update at particular id number.
can anyone help for that ques.

```
path('employees/<int:id>/',views.employeeList.as_view())
```

The above one is url

Comment: is there id field in your serializer? And do you send id inside your request body?

Comment: Where's the id / pk value in input function ? Or is it part of input json ?
Share more code for your model, serializer and input url u r trying. 

Or you can follow this basic tutorial : https://coding-sessions.com/series/drf/ (check the views part 6).

Comment: yes the Id filed in serializer. I didn't give in request body

Comment: not enough code to help.  Are you calling the correct class in url route ? Are you sending input json as request data  and http method as put ? You can put Print statements in your function for debug.

Answer (score 1):

You can write in following way to update the values.
refer the below link https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        '''
        employee updation
        '''
        super(self.__class__, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance

        class Meta:

            model = Employee 
            fields = ('__all__')
```